# Trying to call Method from control page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, boolean

I have been trying to call a method from my .ascx.cs  to my .aspx.cs codebehind. The routine will allow a check box on the .aspx page to hide/show a Textbox and Label on my user control page. Here is what I have so far. I have the visibility of Label and the Textbox set to false in properties.

control Page code behind:

```
public partial class Controls_udc : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private bool MakeVisible(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return (labelComments.Visible == true) && (textComments.Visible == true);
    }
```

code behind for .aspx page:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controls_udc.MakeVisible();
    }

}
```

The compiler error I receive is Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'Controls_udc' does not contain a definition for 'MakeVisible'.

I believe I am on the right track but just need a couple pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MakeVisible` method must be `public` but in your code it is `private`. It should be changed.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to public however I received another compiler error. CS1501: No overload for method 'MakeVisible' takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @jsnhndrsn1985 That's because your method requires two arguments. An object and an EventArgs.

Comment: Add a constactor to Controls_udc page class dont have arguments. Example; public void Controls_udc(){}